# C++ Loop Stuck At First Iteration

Tags: c++, arrays

I was given an assignment to make a program that lets the user enter the total rainfall for each of 12 months into an array of doubles.

The program should calculate and display the total rainfall for the year, the average monthly rainfall, and the months with the highest and lowest amounts.

My professor requires me to simply modify the skeleton she provides for us. And the program compiles just fine the issue is that on the first iteration it shows the first month but stops there.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, any ideas?

Here is the code for the area in question.

```
void getMonthlyRainfalls(double rainfallsArr[], int size, int month){
 cout << "Please type the rainfalls occurring in the month " << (month+1) << ": " ;

 do{
  if (! cin){
     cin.clear();
     cin.ignore(1124, '\n');
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
      cin >> rainfallsArr[month];

  if (!cin || rainfallsArr[month] < 0)
      cout << "Please retype the rainfalls occurring in the month " << (month+1) << ": " ;
  } while (!cin || rainfallsArr[month] < 0);
 }
```

Comment: Why are you looping size times to get the rainfall for a single month and repeatably storing that in the same position overwriting the previous? I am confused what size represents if it is not 12. Maybe you should add the values in the loop if there are multiple rainfall totals per month.

Comment: that's kinda the issue i can't seem to figure it out how to fix it i know the issue is with the for loop but i cant see where i went wrong

Comment: I would get rid of both loops however I am still not sure what size is.

Comment: its suppose to be one value per month for one year

Comment: Then delete `for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)`

Answer (score 1):

that is the solution of your assignment

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 double rain_fall[12] , maxi=0 , mini , sum=0; // maxi for the highest  
 //amount mini for the lowest
 for(int i=0; i<12; i++)
{
    cout<<"please enter the total amount of rainfall in the month number "
    <<i+1<< endl;
    cin>>rain_fall[i];
    if(i==0)
        mini=rain_fall[i];  // happened just once to give it an initial 
    value from the array
    if(maxi<rain_fall[i]) // the highest  amount
        maxi=rain_fall[i];
    else if (mini>rain_fall[i])
        mini=rain_fall[i];  // the lowest  amount
    sum+=rain_fall[i];
}
cout<<"the total amount in the year is : "<<sum<< endl;
cout<<"the average amount per month is : "<<sum/12<< endl;
cout<<"the highest  amount in the year is : "<<maxi<< endl;
cout<<"the lowest  amount in the year is : "<<mini<< endl;
return 0;
}
```

what I do here
I made a shortcut to get the highest and the lowest value by compering during
taking the input from the user and here is the explanation of the code ..

first I take the inputs from the user then for the first input and just for one time I give the mini a value cuz it must be given a value from the input of the array cuz if we assign a zero to it and all the months amounts is bigger than zero but the lowest amount for EX is 2 so that will be a bug cuz the if statement that give me the lowest amount will compere if 0>[what ever the value] 
and every time it will be false so mini will keep the zero in it and display it as the lowest value but actually we don`t have a zero in the array and the lowest value is 2 as we assumed above so for that reason mini should have a value that is existed in the array that contain the amounts

after that the we make an if statement to it to compare with the inputs to save the biggest value in it and we assigned a zero to it because any thing will be bigger than zero so if (0<[what ever the value]) will go well and then give false if we get the biggest value already

after that we add the inputs to each other in the sum variable to get the total amount of all months

after that in the cout statement to get the average amount per month U divide the total per the 12 [the number of months ]

Comment: This answer is lacking an explanation.

Comment: I wrote it above .

Answer (score -1):

while (cin && rainfallsArr[month] > 0);

Comment: Can you provide more context to your answer?